# C# working with numbers as strings

Tags: c#

i need to make a program that gets from the user a 3 digit number and print a 6 digit number
EX: input: 123
Output : 112233

Answer (score 3):

The generic way for doing this with an arbitrary number of digit would looks like this:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(input.Length * 2);

foreach (char c in input)
{
   output.append(c);
   output.append(c);
}

Console.WriteLine(output.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Enumerable.Repeat` in a LINQ query:

```
public static String duplicateChars(IEnumerable<Char> input, int factor)
{
    var chars = from c in input
                from cc in Enumerable.Repeat(c, factor)
                select cc;
    return new String(chars.ToArray());
}
```

test:

```
String result = duplicateChars("123", 2);
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/57KzI

Or the short version:

```
new String("123".SelectMany(c => Enumerable.Repeat(c, 2)).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you actually would get any number as input, not specifically three digits.

You can do like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Concat(Console.ReadLine().Select(c => c.ToString() + c.ToString())));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use regex

`var reg = Regex.Replace("123", @"\d", @"$&$&");`

or as a method

`public static string DuplicateChars(string term) 

 { 

 return Regex.Replace(term, @"\d", @"$&$&"); 

 }`